# How to change location and size of JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, layout-manager

I am working on a menu of a game, and I implemented three JButtons on the MenuPanel, however, I can't change the size or location of the JButtons. I have tried the setBounds function without any result. Can anyone help me?

```
public class MenuPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private JButton playKnop, highScoreKnop, quitKnop;
    private MijnProject mainVenster;

    public MenuPanel(MijnProject mainVenster) 
    {
        this.mainVenster = mainVenster;
        playKnop = new JButton("Play");     
        playKnop.addActionListener(this);
        playKnop.setBounds(200, 200, 20, 20);

        quitKnop = new JButton("Quit");
        quitKnop.addActionListener(this);

        highScoreKnop = new JButton("High Scores");
        highScoreKnop.addActionListener(this);

        this.add(playKnop);
        this.add(quitKnop);
        this.add(highScoreKnop);

    }
```

Comment: I suggest that you learn about [LayoutManagers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setSize(int width, int height)` method. For example, if you wanted a  button 100px wide and 20px tall for your quitKnop button, you would write the line

`quitKnop.setSize(100,20);`

As far as locations go, you should look at layout managers, as mentioned first by @Code-Apprentice in the comment below your question. They will allow you to organize your buttons. You should use margins from there to add space. If you want your button to go to a specific point, you can use the `setLocation(int x, int y)` method, but I don't advise it for this situation.

Comment: *"You can use the `setSize(int width, int height)` method."* Not to achieve what was asked in the question. The layout managers would use the preferred size over the size, and even then would adjust some values according to the nature of the layout manager or the constraints used when added. A good example is `BorderLayout`. The `CENTER` component will get all extra space & the component in it is stretched in both width and height to completely fill it. The `PAGE_START / _END` get their preferred height, but R stretched to width. `LINE_START / _END` are stretched in height but get pref. width.